# whitelisting Jfrog Artifactory IP possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, artifactory

We are currently in the process of considering JFrog as our main repository proxy for our Data Science use case development. The workbench will be hosted on AWS but we need to restrict IP access on the workbench itself. Hence, is it possible to whitelist Jfrog using IP, even though I understand that it is a SaaS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. JFrog publishes and updates [the list of NAT IPs](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-are-artifactory-cloud-nated-ips/) for this purpose exactly.