# Jfrog Artifactory (Cloud) IP addresses to whitelist

Tags: artifactory

We are using jfrog cloud to store our artifacts.
At the same time we have to whitelist the IP addresses we have access to, so we can't access ourcompany.jfrog.io.
So, where can we get the list of jfrog public IP addresses?

Tried to use this list https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-are-artifactory-cloud-nated-ips/
(As recommended here [whitelisting Jfrog Artifactory IP possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74357084/whitelisting-jfrog-artifactory-ip-possible))
But the list seems to be for jfrog outgoing traffic only or not up to date, so it doesn't really helps
e.g. if I nslookup ourcompany.jfrog.io the address I am getting is not in any range.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are a SaaS customer, you should have access to the "my.jfrog.com" portal. There, you could add any of the addresses you would like to whitelist and allow access to your instance. See the screenshot below.

Additionally, JFrog supports PrivateLink Connections which may suit your needs, as can be seen in their documentation - [https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-hosting-models-documentation/manage-privatelink-connections.](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-hosting-models-documentation/manage-privatelink-connections)

[image]

Comment: whitelisting on myfrog portal will white list on their side, actually, is that right?
but I need to white list on my side.

Comment: If you are looking for the JFrog Cloud IPs for outgoing requests from your JFrog server, then the original link you sent - https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-are-artifactory-cloud-nated-ips/.

In order to know which region you are in, you could either use dig/nfslookup to your server name, or find it in the MyJFrog Portal.

If neither of these solutions is what you need (outgoing requests from JFrog and incoming to JFrog, then kindly elaborate on your use case.

Comment: My problem are incoming to jfrog connection, so it seems that Private Link is the only solution I have. Thank you!